# Sort or orderBy in pyspark showing strange output

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to sort value in my pyspark dataframe, but its showing me strange output. Instead of sorting by entire number, it is sorting by first digit of entire number

I have tried sort and orderBy method, both are giving same result

```
sdf=spark.read.csv("dummy.txt", header=True)
sdf.sort('1',ascending=False).show()
```

I am getting following output

```
+---+
| 98|
|  9|
|  8|
| 76|
|  7|
| 68|
|  6|
| 54|
|  5|
| 43|
|  4|
| 35|
| 34|
| 34|
|  3|
|  2|
|  2|
|  2|
| 10|
+---+
```

Can any one explain me this thing

Comment: That's a string sort (your input is string of numbers, not ints). You need a natural sort, probably passing `key=int`.

Answer (score 1):

As your column contains data of `String` type, the `String` is being converted into a Sequence of chars and these chars are sorted.It works like a map function.

So, you could do a type cast, and then apply the `orderBy` function to achieve your required result.

```
>>> df
DataFrame[Numb: string]
>>> df.show()
+----+
|Numb|
+----+
|  20|
|  19|
|   1|
| 200|
|  60|
+----+

>>> df.orderBy(df.Numb.cast('int'),ascending=False).show()
+----+
|Numb|
+----+
| 200|
|  60|
|  20|
|  19|
|   1|
+----+
```